# Metaphor, simile, or idiom for stating that something improved one’s self-confidence

Tags: idiom-requests, metaphors, simile

What’s a nice and quirky metaphor, simile, or idiom for saying that something improved my self-confidence and made me dream higher, for example in the following context?

> These competitions not only provided a platform to test myself, but they also [improved my self confidence, and spurred me to dream higher].

Comment: The most direct idiom is "*boosted* my self-confidence".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

> - energised (UK) energized (US), or reenergised/reenergized
> - invigorated or reinvigorated
> - activated or reactivated
> - animated (or reanimated)
> - revived (or revivified)
> - refreshed
> - exhilarated
> - revitalized
> - quickened
> - galvanized (UK) galvanized (US)
> - gave me a new lease on life
> - restored
> - jump-started me
> - opened my eyes
> - rocked my world
> - reawakened
> - recreated
> - regenerated
> - rejuvenated
> - renewed
> - rekindled the fire within me
> - lifted me up

Answer (score 1):

The word ***prod*** works here (also in the idiom ***prod someone into something***).

> These competitions not only provided a platform to test myself, but
>   they also ***prodded*** me to dream higher.
>   These competitions not only provided a platform to test myself, but
>   they also ***prodded*** me into dreaming higher.

ODO:

> **[prod](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prod)**
>   *VERB*
>   **1.1** *Stimulate or persuade (someone who is reluctant or slow) to do something*
>
> ‘At the same time, I'm prodding the actors and encouraging them to dig
>   down inside themselves.’
>   ‘Simultaneously, his urge to challenge the
>   limits prodded him to attempt breaking world records.’

TFD(idioms):

> **[prod someone into something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/prodded)**
>   *to motivate someone into doing something; to provoke someone into action.*
>   Do I have to prod you
>   into going?
>   Can't you volunteer for once? We will prod her into
>   getting it done on time.
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by
>   The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.

Answer (score 1):

> These competitions not only provided a platform to test myself, but they also made me believe in myself, like **Popeye and his can of spinach**.

Reference: https://youtu.be/pcOrSWr2HLU?list=PLSDZ-wemAt9ZngIHj-0LMslRZnNJoQ7m6

Answer (score 0):

I am no native speaker, hence I've tried searching for such idioms, and stumbled upon this [site](http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-categories/ambition-determination/ambition-determ2.html). Found three sort of fitting the description:

> **go into overdrive** - if someone or something goes into overdrive, they
> begin to work very hard or start to perform intensely,
>
> **have one's heart set on** - someone who has their heart set on something
> is determined to obtain something they want very much,
>
> **hitch one's wagon to a star** - someone who hitches their wagon to a star
> has great ambitions and is very determined to reach their goal.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

> These competitions not only provided a platform to test myself, but they also strengthened my foundation.`

The word "platform" is used earlier in the sentence. Using "foundation" keeps with the "building" theme.

Removing some words may make the sentence bolder:

> These competitions provided a platform to test myself and strengthen my foundation`

Answer (score 0):

How about [emboldened me](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/embolden). You would probably need to add a bit more to the end of your sentence such as:

> These competitions not only provided a platform to test myself, but they also **emboldened me** *to try for greater things*.

If you do that *emboldened* should work well.

Answer (score 0):

You can say boosted or took-off like a rocket; aerial words.

1. These competitions not only provided a platform to test myself, but they also boosted my self confidence.
2. These competitions not only provided a platform to test myself, they also made my self-confidence soar.
3. These competitions provided a platform to test myself, and my self-confidence took off like a rocket. I dreamed of going higher and higher and achieving more and more.

Answer (score 0):

You could say "they put wind in my sails".

Sails are a common metaphor for confidence and self-assurance and you can use the metaphor for  having it or lacking it.

> It took all the wind out of my sails.

Comment: Without any explanation or reference, this is a comment rather than an answer

Comment: It seemed rather self-evident to me that it was a metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

Another idiom which works here is "*give wing to*".

> These competitions not only provided a platform to test myself, but
> they also ****gave wing*** to my [talent/skill/career]*.

TFD(idioms):

> **[give wing to (something)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+wing+to)**
>
> 1. To allow, facilitate, or foster something.
>    My mother's encouragement really gave wing to my career as an artist.